# What should be the optimal dimensions of the container (i.e. height and radius) which will minimize the amount of material needed to construct

Tags: calculus

Lets say, you want to make a cylindrical container which has a bottom and sides, but no top (i.e. no lid).  The volume of this container must be 30 cubic cm. What should be the optimal dimensions of the container (i.e. height and radius) which will minimize the amount of material needed to construct the can.(a) What is the constraint function (i.e. what is given)? Write an equation for it.[4pt]

(b) What is the objective function (i.e. what are you trying to minimize)? Write an equation for it.[4pt]

(c) Draw a picture of the can.[2pt]

(d) Substitute the constraint function into the objective function so that the objective function depends only on one variable.  What are the critical points of the objective function? [5pt]

(e) Using the second derivative test, decide if the critical point is a maximum or minimum.[5pt]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: This smells like homework. So, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Say that $R$ is the radius and $H$ the height of the container. 
The volume $V$ is fixed, $V = \pi R^2 H$, the area $A$ must be minimized, $A = 2 \pi R H + \pi R^2$ (open top).

Using the fact that $H = V/(\pi R^2)$, you can substitute into $A$ and find
$A(R) = \pi R^2 + 2 V/R$, where $V$ is a fixed constant. Now use the first and second derivative of the function $A(R)$ with respect to $R$ to find the final answer.

Alternatively, instead of substituting $H$, you can also try to substitute $R= (V/(\pi H))^{1/2}$ to find $A(H)$, then derive with respect to $H$.